# Removing ID at the end of Get Request from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, rest-api

I have written a custom html script which is saved in a custom block and displayed on a product page, which is a GET request and fetches the data from a node service on another service,

when the request is sent , Magento is adding a Number which im not sure why is it adding, it is not the cache version or the SID(&_=1567760378803).

https://test.test.eu/api/getProducts?&type=101&height=5&unit=1002&breadth=3&length=10&_=156776037880....

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

To disable SID from the storefront go to:

1. Magento dashboard > Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefrontand set its value to No.
2. Re-index Magento
3. Refresh Magento cache

For more detail please visit [**This Link**](https://www.shoaibrehman.com/solved-remove-sid-session_id-url-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

***Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No***

[image]

***After that run command (ssh)***

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

> *The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento
>   powers one website and one store from one installation (database).*
>
> *Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while
>   navigating across these websites/stores.*
>
> *I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the
>   user's location/state for the current website/store.*
>
> *If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's safe to disable the SID on the frontend.*